# Are .so files in Fedora considered ELF files?

Tags: linux, executable, dynamic-linking, file-format

ELF 'Executable and Linkable Format' So if I generate Shared Object files `.so` are those considered ELF files?

Comment: They're not _considered_ ELF, they _are_ ELF files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you generate them on linux for native use.  You can see this via `file`:

```
> file mylib.so
mylib.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object [...]
```